# Auto Send feature in Custom Keyboard Extension iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, custom-keyboard

I've implemented Custom Keyboard Extension in my app, and have a UITableView in it. When I click on the cell of the UITableView which has a text label, I want the text to be able to Auto Send (some apps support AutoSend i.e. SnapChat, Tiktok, Safari).

I searched through UITextDocumentProxy, but wasn't able to achieve the above scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Some Auto Sending apps like SnapChat, Tiktok, Safari I have done through this function, when you want to send a text automatically after you want to send text
then call

```
textDocumentProxy?.return()
```

extension

```
extension UIKeyInput {
    func `return`() -> Void{
         insertText("\n")
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working, the cursor just jumps to the next line.

Comment: @NikhilViradiya it works on Sending apps like SnapChat, Tiktok, please try again on these apps

Comment: you can textDocumentProxy.insertText(yourText) after maybe can delay 0.2 s before call textDocumentProxy?.return()

Comment: Its working now, but I had to call the function using DispatchQueue

Comment: Thank you @Anh vu

Comment: i forgot this, is it working

Comment: Yes, its working now.