# Auto Enter feature in Custom Keyboard Extension iOS Swift in 3rd party host app

Tags: swift, enter, ios-keyboard-extension, textdocumentproxy

I've implemented Custom Keyboard Extension in my app. When I use this with my other 3rd party host app, and connected to hardware barcode scanner, I want it to do auto enter when there is barcode read.

I able do this with the help here -> [auto-send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70224575/auto-send-feature-in-custom-keyboard-extension-ios-swift), but i noticed that if i do delete the text with backspace button and do scan again, this will not work anymore.